# How could I detect mouseDown event outside my NSView?

Tags: macos, nsview, mousedown

I create my custom NSView when a certain button is clicked, and I want to close this custom view if your click outside the NSView. But it seem that I could not receive mouseDown event in this custom NSView. Is there anyone know how to fit it ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share two other solutions that unlike the NSEvent approach, doesn't have the sandbox limitations.

A cover window. 
It's more involved code and a good exercise in learning what's possible with windows and views. But worth learning and knowing.

Create a borderless window that takes up the whole screen. The borderless window can then handle mouse events.

A tracking area. 
This approach is similar

Comment: sandbox limitation?

Comment: You might run into sandbox issues trying to use a global event monitor or CGEvent tap for events outside your app. If you are sandboxed.

Comment: Makes sense, or else one could sneak in key/mouse loggers. I Will use local event monitor instead. And then use the windowDidResize() to trigger mouse click outside the window. I guess one could log the NsEvent.mouseLocation when this event happens and still pass the app sandbox requirement.

Comment: Yes. That will work. If you create an invisible borderless window, you can just implement mouseDown: in the window controller or view controller of the main view. That's the coverwindow/screenwindow approach. It gets coordinates. If you don't need to intercept it, you just call [super mouseDown:event] to forward it on up the chain. The advantage of mouseDown: is simplicity. Your app doesn't even need to be at the front, just have a window level set high for the invisible window. hard part is multiple displays.

Comment: And split screen I suppose. Great to know about the alternative! I just needed the mouseDownOutsideWindow event to close a programatic ComboBox Window on click outside. NSNotification works for this case.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use NSEvent global event monitor. 
Then you may need to convert the mouse NSPoint to your view coordinates and use the function NSPointInRect to see if it is inside or not.

Comment: The NSEvent Programming Guide has sample code in the docs showing how to do this.

Comment: Here is my solution : _eventMonitor = [NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *event)
    {
        NSPoint pt = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
        int     x = pt.x;
        int     y = pt.y;

        if (PtInRect(rectListBox, x, y))
            return event;
        /***** do something here *****/
        return (NSEvent *) nil;
    }];